# Pass void function to a String in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, parameter-passing

I have created a void function name `-(void)checkPara` .

Now i have called it to my desire location in a code. I have declared a global variable of `NSString *Parameters;`.

I want to store that function `-(void)checkPara` in this Parameter string, how can I do this in Objective c? I have to send it to the server through `POST` request.
My function is,

```
-(void)checkPara{

    NSUserDefaults *successDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *success= [successDefaults valueForKey:@"Success"];
    if ([success isEqual:@"Success"]){

        NSUserDefaults *successDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        _name.text=[successDefaults valueForKey:@"name"];
        _email.text=[successDefaults valueForKey:@"email"];
        phones=[successDefaults valueForKey:@"number"];

        flooring=_floor;
        property=_propfor;

        NSString *phone = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",_code.text,_mobile.text,_number1.text];
        NSLog(@"%@",phone);

        NSLog(@"GGGG %@",flooring);
        NSLog(@"HHHH %@",property);


        NSString *iii1 = _imgurl1;
        NSString *iii2 = _imgurl2;
        NSString *iii3 = _imgurl3;
        NSString *iii4 = _imgurl4;
        NSString *iii5 = _imgurl5;
        NSString *iii6 = _imgurl6;

        NSLog(@"OYE OYE: %@", iii1);
        NSLog(@"OYE OYE: %@", iii2);
        NSLog(@"OYE OYE: %@", iii3);
        NSLog(@"OYE OYE: %@", iii4);
        NSLog(@"OYE OYE: %@", iii5);
        NSLog(@"OYE OYE: %@", iii6);

        NSString * timestamp1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];
        NSLog(@"%@",timestamp1);

        NSString * timestamp2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];

        NSLog(@"%@",timestamp2);


        NSString * timestamp3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];
        NSLog(@"%@",timestamp3);


        NSString * timestamp4 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];

        NSLog(@"%@",timestamp4);

        NSString * timestamp5 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];

        NSLog(@"%@",timestamp5);

        NSString * timestamp6 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];

        NSLog(@"%@",timestamp6);


        parameter1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&email=%@&phone=%@&propertytitle=%@&propertyfor=%@&propertytype=%@&propertytypeiner=%@&propertyprice=%@&propertyavail=%@&landarea=%@&noofrooms=%@&noofbathrooms=%@&noofloors=%@&description=%@&structureofproperty=%@&structureofflooring=%@&wallsstructure=%@&doorsstructure=%@&=electricalstructure=%@&location=%@&country=%@&city=%@&imageurl1=%@&timestamp1=%@&imageurl2=%@&timestamp2=%@&imageurl3=%@&timestamp3=%@&imageurl4=%@&timestamp4=%@&imageurl5=%@&timestamp5=%@&imageurl6=%@&timestamp6%@",_name.text,_email.text,phones,_tites,property,_proptype,_propoption,_propprice,_propavail,_area,_room,_bath,flooring,_detail,@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",_Location.text,_but1.titleLabel.text,_but2.titleLabel.text,iii1,_timestamp1,iii2,_timestamp2,iii3,_timestamp3,iii4,_timestamp4,iii5,_timestamp5,iii6,_timestamp6];

    }
    else{
        flooring=_floor;
        property=_propfor;

        NSString *phone = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",_code.text,_mobile.text,_number1.text];
        NSLog(@"%@",phone);

        NSLog(@"GGGG %@",flooring);
        NSLog(@"HHHH %@",property);


        NSString *iii1 = _imgurl1;
        NSString *iii2 = _imgurl2;
        NSString *iii3 = _imgurl3;
        NSString *iii4 = _imgurl4;
        NSString *iii5 = _imgurl5;
        NSString *iii6 = _imgurl6;

        NSLog(@"OYE OYE: %@", iii1);
        NSLog(@"OYE OYE: %@", iii2);
        NSLog(@"OYE OYE: %@", iii3);
        NSLog(@"OYE OYE: %@", iii4);
        NSLog(@"OYE OYE: %@", iii5);
        NSLog(@"OYE OYE: %@", iii6);

        NSString * timestamp1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];
        NSLog(@"%@",timestamp1);

        NSString * timestamp2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];

        NSLog(@"%@",timestamp2);


        NSString * timestamp3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];
        NSLog(@"%@",timestamp3);


        NSString * timestamp4 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];

        NSLog(@"%@",timestamp4);

        NSString * timestamp5 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];

        NSLog(@"%@",timestamp5);

        NSString * timestamp6 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];

        NSLog(@"%@",timestamp6);


        parameter1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&email=%@&phone=%@&propertytitle=%@&propertyfor=%@&propertytype=%@&propertytypeiner=%@&propertyprice=%@&propertyavail=%@&landarea=%@&noofrooms=%@&noofbathrooms=%@&noofloors=%@&description=%@&structureofproperty=%@&structureofflooring=%@&wallsstructure=%@&doorsstructure=%@&=electricalstructure=%@&location=%@&country=%@&city=%@&imageurl1=%@&timestamp1=%@&imageurl2=%@&timestamp2=%@&imageurl3=%@&timestamp3=%@&imageurl4=%@&timestamp4=%@&imageurl5=%@&timestamp5=%@&imageurl6=%@&timestamp6%@",_name.text,_email.text,phone,_tites,property,_proptype,_propoption,_propprice,_propavail,_area,_room,_bath,flooring,_detail,@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",_Location.text,_but1.titleLabel.text,_but2.titleLabel.text,iii1,_timestamp1,iii2,_timestamp2,iii3,_timestamp3,iii4,_timestamp4,iii5,_timestamp5,iii6,_timestamp6];

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to store string ?

Comment: Store what? Could you give an example? You want to keep a `@selector()`?

Comment: i have a condition in that void function , now i want to to get this void function in a string and pass the string forward to server as a parameter. @Nirmalsinh

Comment: @HamzaImran can you give me function? So I can give you a proper answer.

Comment: Parameter=[self sheckPara]; i'm writting like this but facing an error that it could not be write like this. @Larme

Comment: Why is it "void"? Give a real example, we could help you on maybe modify your logic to a better one.

Comment: Can you post whole funcation?

Comment: Either you replace void with NSString* or you use a global property.

Comment: i have to pass only variable there to server. @Nirmalsinh

Comment: What is parameter1 used for?

Comment: Are you implementing Login function with Name & Email? with Remember Me option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get any value if your **function's** return type is **void**. To get string from function you need to following changes:

```
-(NSString *)yourFuncation{
             // Do your all stuff which you wanted to
               return FINAL_STRING;
    }
```

Here is your updated funcation:

```
-(NSString *)checkPara{

    NSUserDefaults *successDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *success= [successDefaults valueForKey:@"Success"];
    if ([success isEqual:@"Success"]){

        NSUserDefaults *successDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        _name.text=[successDefaults valueForKey:@"name"];
        _email.text=[successDefaults valueForKey:@"email"];
        phones=[successDefaults valueForKey:@"number"];

        flooring=_floor;
        property=_propfor;

        NSString *phone = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",_code.text,_mobile.text,_number1.text];
        NSLog(@"%@",phone);

        NSLog(@"GGGG %@",flooring);
        NSLog(@"HHHH %@",property);



        NSString *iii1 = _imgurl1;
        NSString *iii2 = _imgurl2;
        NSString *iii3 = _imgurl3;
        NSString *iii4 = _imgurl4;
        NSString *iii5 = _imgurl5;
        NSString *iii6 = _imgurl6;

        NSLog(@"OYE OYE: %@", iii1);
        NSLog(@"OYE OYE: %@", iii2);
        NSLog(@"OYE OYE: %@", iii3);
        NSLog(@"OYE OYE: %@", iii4);
        NSLog(@"OYE OYE: %@", iii5);
        NSLog(@"OYE OYE: %@", iii6);

        NSString * timestamp1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];
        NSLog(@"%@",timestamp1);

        NSString * timestamp2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];

        NSLog(@"%@",timestamp2);



        NSString * timestamp3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];
        NSLog(@"%@",timestamp3);


        NSString * timestamp4 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];

        NSLog(@"%@",timestamp4);

        NSString * timestamp5 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];

        NSLog(@"%@",timestamp5);

        NSString * timestamp6 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];

        NSLog(@"%@",timestamp6);




        NSString *parameter1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&email=%@&phone=%@&propertytitle=%@&propertyfor=%@&propertytype=%@&propertytypeiner=%@&propertyprice=%@&propertyavail=%@&landarea=%@&noofrooms=%@&noofbathrooms=%@&noofloors=%@&description=%@&structureofproperty=%@&structureofflooring=%@&wallsstructure=%@&doorsstructure=%@&=electricalstructure=%@&location=%@&country=%@&city=%@&imageurl1=%@&timestamp1=%@&imageurl2=%@&timestamp2=%@&imageurl3=%@&timestamp3=%@&imageurl4=%@&timestamp4=%@&imageurl5=%@&timestamp5=%@&imageurl6=%@&timestamp6%@",_name.text,_email.text,phones,_tites,property,_proptype,_propoption,_propprice,_propavail,_area,_room,_bath,flooring,_detail,@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",_Location.text,_but1.titleLabel.text,_but2.titleLabel.text,iii1,_timestamp1,iii2,_timestamp2,iii3,_timestamp3,iii4,_timestamp4,iii5,_timestamp5,iii6,_timestamp6];

        return parameter1;
    }
    else{
        flooring=_floor;
        property=_propfor;

        NSString *phone = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",_code.text,_mobile.text,_number1.text];
        NSLog(@"%@",phone);

        NSLog(@"GGGG %@",flooring);
        NSLog(@"HHHH %@",property);



        NSString *iii1 = _imgurl1;
        NSString *iii2 = _imgurl2;
        NSString *iii3 = _imgurl3;
        NSString *iii4 = _imgurl4;
        NSString *iii5 = _imgurl5;
        NSString *iii6 = _imgurl6;

        NSLog(@"OYE OYE: %@", iii1);
        NSLog(@"OYE OYE: %@", iii2);
        NSLog(@"OYE OYE: %@", iii3);
        NSLog(@"OYE OYE: %@", iii4);
        NSLog(@"OYE OYE: %@", iii5);
        NSLog(@"OYE OYE: %@", iii6);

        NSString * timestamp1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];
        NSLog(@"%@",timestamp1);

        NSString * timestamp2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];

        NSLog(@"%@",timestamp2);



        NSString * timestamp3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];
        NSLog(@"%@",timestamp3);


        NSString * timestamp4 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];

        NSLog(@"%@",timestamp4);

        NSString * timestamp5 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];

        NSLog(@"%@",timestamp5);

        NSString * timestamp6 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];

        NSLog(@"%@",timestamp6);




        parameter1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&email=%@&phone=%@&propertytitle=%@&propertyfor=%@&propertytype=%@&propertytypeiner=%@&propertyprice=%@&propertyavail=%@&landarea=%@&noofrooms=%@&noofbathrooms=%@&noofloors=%@&description=%@&structureofproperty=%@&structureofflooring=%@&wallsstructure=%@&doorsstructure=%@&=electricalstructure=%@&location=%@&country=%@&city=%@&imageurl1=%@&timestamp1=%@&imageurl2=%@&timestamp2=%@&imageurl3=%@&timestamp3=%@&imageurl4=%@&timestamp4=%@&imageurl5=%@&timestamp5=%@&imageurl6=%@&timestamp6%@",_name.text,_email.text,phone,_tites,property,_proptype,_propoption,_propprice,_propavail,_area,_room,_bath,flooring,_detail,@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",_Location.text,_but1.titleLabel.text,_but2.titleLabel.text,iii1,_timestamp1,iii2,_timestamp2,iii3,_timestamp3,iii4,_timestamp4,iii5,_timestamp5,iii6,_timestamp6];

        return parameter1;
    }


}
```

You can call this function like:

```
NSString *parameter =  [self checkPara];
```

So it will return string and stored into **Parameter** object. And then you send it to server.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. @Nirmalsinh

Answer (score 1):

```
Parameter = [self checkPara];

-(NSString*)checkPara{
       NSString * parameter1;
       if (){
           //Your code
           parameter1 = //
       }
       else{
           //Your code
           parameter1 = //
       }

return parameter1
}
```

Comment: i have changed void to like this -(NSString*)checkPara as u write but at closing curlie brace of function i'm getting an error that control reaches to non void function. @Explorer.AS

Comment: @HamzaImran check again. Where did u define parameter1?

Comment: Thanks. @Explorer.AS